# Move files to correct date directories based on filename

Tags: bash, mv

Some of my files are in incorrect directories, and I am trying to move them to their correct location.

example:

directory 20180622 will contain only file names having 20180622 in their name

if 20180622 directory contains a file having 20180623 in its name then it is a misplaced file and should goto corresponding correct directory viz 20180623
directory structure is fixed (fortunately)

```
date1/a/b/someprefix.date1.somesuffix #no problem
date1/a/b/someprefix.date2.somesuffix # problem
date2/c/d/someprefix.date2.somesuffix # no problem
date2/e/f/someprefix.date3.somesuffix # problem

date1/a/b/someprefix.date1.somesuffix
date2/a/b/someprefix.date2.somesuffix # problem fixed
date2/c/d/someprefix.date2.somesuffix
date3/e/f/someprefix.date3.somesuffix #problem fixed
```

using `find . -type f`  i get list of all files but not getting how to `mv` the files to correct place. 
`someprefix` can be anything (it may contain a dot aswell so cut is not a good way to extract date from filename) `$f =~ (.*)(201[5-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(.*)` is what i am trying to get date extracted from filename

Comment: Are `someprefix` and `somesuffix` always the same?

Comment: unfortunately no :( , it could be anytext, i can only assure date will always be contained , however somesuffix always ends with `.gz` . I can run multiple commands for all set of someprefix if there is a solution with that

Comment: Given that Python is part of your username, I suggest using that instead of Bash to solve this problem.  It will be easier to implement.

Comment: You can learn how to manipulate bash parameters here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with bash regular expression matching, you can't extract *all* submatches, so I'm falling back to grep to find all the dates.

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  while IFS= read -d "" -r filename; do
    mapfile -t dates < <(echo "$filename" | grep -Eo '\<201[5-8][0-9]{4}\>')
    if [[ ${#dates[@]} -eq 2 ]] && [[ ${dates[0]} != ${dates[1]} ]]; then
      destdir=$(dirname "$filename" | sed "s/${dates[0]}/${dates[1]}/")
      mkdir -p "$destdir"
      mv -v "$filename" "$destdir"
    fi
  done
```

---

Testing:

```
$ tree
.
├── 20180621
│   └── a
│       └── b
│           ├── a.20180621.txt
│           └── foo.20180701.bar
└── 20180701
    └── c
        └── d
            └── ok.20180701

6 directories, 3 files
```

We have one file that should be moved

```
$ find . -type f -print0 |
   while IFS= read -d "" -r filename; do
     mapfile -t dates < <(echo "$filename" | grep -Eo '\<201[5-8][0-9]{4}\>')
     if [[ ${#dates[@]} -eq 2 ]] && [[ ${dates[0]} != ${dates[1]} ]]; then
       destdir=$(dirname "$filename" | sed "s/${dates[0]}/${dates[1]}/")
       mkdir -p "$destdir"
       mv -v "$filename" "$destdir"
     fi
   done
'./20180621/a/b/foo.20180701.bar' -> './20180701/a/b/foo.20180701.bar'
```

and the result

```
$ tree
.
├── 20180621
│   └── a
│       └── b
│           └── a.20180621.txt
└── 20180701
    ├── a
    │   └── b
    │       └── foo.20180701.bar
    └── c
        └── d
            └── ok.20180701

8 directories, 3 files
```

---

Without relying on grep, and this is a tweak to Arount's answer:

```
find 20+([0-9])/ -type f -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d "" -r filename; do
        dirdate=${filename%%/*}
        if [[ "$(basename "$filename")" =~ 20[0-9]{6} ]]; then
            filedate=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
            if [[ $dirdate != $filedate ]]; then
                dest=${filename/$dirdate/$filedate}
                echo mkdir -p "$(dirname "$dest")"
                echo mv -v "$filename" "$dest"
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy to handle, you just need a loop and a if.

```
for path in $(find . -type f); do
    dirdate=$(echo $path | cut -d '/' -f 2)
    filedate=$(basename $path | cut -d '.' -f 2)

    if [[ $dirdate != $filedate ]]; then
        mv $path $(dirname $path | sed "s/$dirdate/$filedate/g")
    fi
done
```

The idea here is extremly simple: It loop in files getting the whole file path (`./date1/a/b/prefix.date.suffix`) and check if `date1` is equal to `date`. If not it move the file to the same path where `date1` was replaced by `date`.

### Edit for comments

If you want to handle several delemiters for your filenames you just need to change the `filedate=` line like:

```
filedate=$(basename $path | awk -F'[._\-]' '{print $2}' 2> /dev/null)
```

It's a bit more trickier but let's say it's Bash.

`2> /dev/null` is to make `awk`'s warnings silents.

Comment: yes that almost works, but prefix and suffix can have `dot .` or `-` or `_`as seprator 
so cutting date from filename is a problem for me now. i need a regex which gives me `filenamedate=$(echo $path | cut -d '/' -f 5)` now say i get sometext_date-sometext or dometext-date-sometext or sometext.date.sometext etc. So a regex that can extract pattern 201[5-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] from above would be ideal. date is alwasy in YYYYMMDD format seperated by something at both ends [anything]YYYYMMDD[anything]

Comment: something like `$f =~ (.*)(201[5-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])(.*)` not sure though, just adding here as my try